# Why an "Invoking rollback for transaction" on a @Transactional annotation

Tags: spring, transactions

I am confused with some exception handling within a transaction REST controller.

I have an admin service that looks like:

```
@Override
public SearchedAdminsEvent search(SearchAdminsEvent searchAdminsEvent) {
    Page<Admin> admins = adminRepository.search(searchAdminsEvent.getSearchTerm(), searchAdminsEvent.getPageRequest());
    if (admins.getTotalElements() == 0) {
        throw new SearchedAdminsNotFoundException(searchAdminsEvent.getSearchTerm());
    } else {
        List<EventAdmin> eventAdmins = EventAdmin.newEventAdminsFrom(admins.getContent()); 
        return new SearchedAdminsEvent(searchAdminsEvent.getSearchTerm(), searchAdminsEvent.getPageRequest(), eventAdmins);
    }
}
```

I have a REST controller that looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<AdminResource>> search(@RequestParam(value = "searchTerm", required = true) String searchTerm, @RequestParam(value = "page", required = true, defaultValue = "0") int page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = true, defaultValue = "10") int size, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    Pageable pageRequest = buildPageRequest(page, size);
    SearchedAdminsEvent searchedAdminsEvent;
    try {
        searchedAdminsEvent = adminService.search(new SearchAdminsEvent(searchTerm, pageRequest));            
    } catch (SearchedAdminsNotFoundException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<AdminResource>>(responseHeaders, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    responseHeaders.setLocation(builder.path("/admin/search").queryParam("searchTerm", searchTerm).queryParam("page", page).queryParam("size", size).buildAndExpand(searchedAdminsEvent.getSearchTerm()).toUri());
    List<AdminResource> adminResources = adminResourceAssembler.toResources(searchedAdminsEvent.getEventAdmins());
    ResponseEntity<List<AdminResource>> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<List<AdminResource>>(adminResources, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

It makes use of the @Transactional(readOnly = true) annotation.

If this annotation is present AND if no searched items were found then it gives the following exception:

```
2014-06-30 16:22:39,736 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,736 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,736 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,736 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1f9bfd9] rollback-only 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,736 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1f9bfd9] rollback-only 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,736 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1f9bfd9] rollback-only 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,737 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction commit 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,737 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction commit 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,737 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction commit 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,737 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1f9bfd9] 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,737 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1f9bfd9] 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,737 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1f9bfd9] 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,754 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1f9bfd9] after transaction 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,754 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1f9bfd9] after transaction 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,754 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1f9bfd9] after transaction 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,755 DEBUG  [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,755 DEBUG  [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,755 DEBUG  [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,760 DEBUG  [ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.resource.AdminResource>> com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController.search(java.lang.String,int,int,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)]: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,760 DEBUG  [ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.resource.AdminResource>> com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController.search(java.lang.String,int,int,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)]: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,760 DEBUG  [ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.resource.AdminResource>> com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController.search(java.lang.String,int,int,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)]: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,762 DEBUG  [ResponseStatusExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.resource.AdminResource>> com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController.search(java.lang.String,int,int,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)]: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,762 DEBUG  [ResponseStatusExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.resource.AdminResource>> com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController.search(java.lang.String,int,int,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)]: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,762 DEBUG  [ResponseStatusExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.resource.AdminResource>> com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController.search(java.lang.String,int,int,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)]: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,763 DEBUG  [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.resource.AdminResource>> com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController.search(java.lang.String,int,int,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)]: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,763 DEBUG  [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.resource.AdminResource>> com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController.search(java.lang.String,int,int,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)]: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,763 DEBUG  [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.resource.AdminResource>> com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController.search(java.lang.String,int,int,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)]: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly 
2014-06-30 16:22:39,773 DEBUG  [DispatcherServlet] Could not complete request 
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:522)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ebae6d18.search(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:513)
    ... 73 more
2014-06-30 16:22:39,773 DEBUG  [DispatcherServlet] Could not complete request 
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:522)
```

If I remove the annotation then all is fine and the response contains the searched items.

I suppose an exception is thrown when no searched items are found, which triggers the transaction rollback message.

Here is the exception handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(SearchedAdminsNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ErrorInfo> searchedAdminsNotFoundException(HttpServletRequest request, SearchedAdminsNotFoundException e) {
    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    String errorMessage = localizeErrorMessage("error.admin.search.not.found", new Object[] { e.getSearchTerm() });
    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorInfo>(new ErrorInfo(url, errorMessage), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Is there any way to see somewhere in the log the inner exception which triggered the transaction rollback one ?

I'm on Spring 3.2.9.RELEASE and Hibernate 3.6.10.Final.

Here is the root cause:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/learnintouch-rest] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly] with root cause
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:513)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller.AdminController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b11b3634.search(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

UPDATE: Here is my guess... The exception is caught, so it is not displayed in the log. The annotation rolls back the transaction, even if the exception was caught. Am I right ? In that case, how to handle, i.e., catch exceptions in controllers, if using the annotation ?

Kind Regards,

Stephane Eybert

Comment: The thing that stands out from your log, in my opinion, is the "Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only" message. Is `adminService.search()` method transactional, as well?

Comment: There is something I don't understand: obviously, your `adminService.search` method is expected to throw a `SearchedAdminsNotFoundException` if I'm not mistaken. Why do you want to see the exception in logs? I asked in my previous comment if `adminService.search` is configured to be transactional, as well (through `@Transactional` or something similar). If you have that transactional and you do handle `SearchedAdminsNotFoundException` in some way (by rolling back the `adminService.search` transaction) but at the same time catching the exception in the controller looks unusual to me.

Comment: Assuming my above guess is correct, don't allow the `adminService.search` method transaction to rollback in case of that exception and let the exception flow until the controller where you catch it and handle it in some other way. But, as I said, this depends on how your `adminService.search` method is configured, transactionally speaking.

Comment: Hi Andrei, no, the admin service is not specifically marked as transactional. In my case, only the controller is mmarked as being transactional. I wonder if it's better to mark the service or the controller as being transactional.

Comment: Definitely the service.

Comment: All right, thanks for that tip.

Comment: I now understand trying to catch an exception, when it was swallowed up by a rolled back transaction, didn't make sense .

Comment: Would you advise for custom exceptions popping up to the controller in the form of end-user properties message like I did ?

Comment: Any tip on end-user feedback in the controller in case of a transactional exception ?

Comment: You could do that, yes. I'm wondering why you throw an exception though, but I guess this would work as well. The other option would be to handle a 0 value for counting admins (or whatever you are counting in that query) or a greater than 0 value. Meaning, your service method executes the query and returns the value. If it's 0 then you prepare for the user an appropriate web page, otherwise something else.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I wonder how I can mark your reply as a solution... I hope I played the SO as it's supposed to...

Comment: You cannot mark a comment as a solution, only answers. I've added one below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could propagate the exceptions to controllers, yes, but I'd choose marking the service methods as transactional. I'm wondering why you throw an exception though, but I guess this would work as well. The other option would be to handle a 0 value for counting admins (or whatever you are counting in that query) or a greater than 0 value. Meaning, your service method executes the query and returns the value. If it's 0 then you prepare for the user an appropriate web page, otherwise something else.

Comment: I agree that no admins found is not really exceptional. So throwing an exception for that might be overkill. I wonder if there is any such thing as a business exception. Your rule of thumb on when to throw an exception and when to return a value ? Cheers.